# array_filter posting Array as result in DB instead of value

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I am trying to remove all the null values from array, but instead of this in my DB the record is: **Array** and not the actual value.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':number', $this->number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

what I am using is:

```
if( isset( $_POST['number'])) 
  { $this->number = array_filter($_POST['number']); 
  }
```

**Array:**

```
number[0] 32321    
number[1]   
number[2]
```

Expected Result is an array, or variable where there is only one value which is not null  `number[0] 32321`

Any help is welcome.

Comment: `array_filter` returns you an array of *all* the values in the array that aren't null (or otherwise empty), even if there's only one of them

Comment: What do you expect the result to be if there are more than 1 non-null values in the array?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I need to get only the value inserted in the DB, if last element of the array is 0 this is what is being inserted. This is why I am trying to remove the Null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing `"Array"` (the standard string representation of an array in PHP) because `array_filter` returns an array, not a single value, so what you have in `$this->number` is not `32321`, it is `array(32321)`. If you change your error reporting setting, you'll see notices about array to string conversion.

You can add the assignment to the `if` condition (or add another nested if, if you don't like to do that). Then if `array_filter` returns an empty array you won't go into the `if` block.

```
if (isset( $_POST['number']) && $this->number = array_filter($_POST['number'])) {
    // insert values from $this->number into your database
}
```

Inside the `if` block, when you try to insert values, in order to not get `"Array"` like you're currently getting, you can do multiple inserts by looping over the `$this->number` array and executing your prepared statement for each item:

```
foreach ($this->number as $number) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':number', $number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Or if you only want to insert the first thing in `$_POST['number']` and ignore any other non-null values, then you can bind the first value from the array:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':number', reset($this->number), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_filter will always return you an array of elements, it will remove null values but before assigned it to `$this->number` you have to loop through your returned array and then insert to DB. or you can implode that array and store it in DB as csv.